# How to Rewrite URL in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have URLs with two query parameters e.g. `/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=retail&q=analyst` and I'd like to redirect those URLs to `/list-of-%2-skills-in-%1` .

I have tried the code below which looks at the query "industry" and "q" to build the destination URL: `/list-of-%2-skills-in-%1`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^industry=(.*)&q=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^skills/keywords/list\.php$ /list-of-%2-skills-in-%1? [L,R=301]
```

I'm expecting: `/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=retail&q=analyst` to redirect to `/list-of-analyst-skills-in-retail` which it does but I have a 404 content not found.
 Can someone point me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the destination path `/list-of-%2-skills-in-%1` doesn't exist on your server. You need to rewrite this path to the existent file `/skills/keywords/list.php?industry=retail&q=analyst` .

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#redirect /skills/keywords/list.php?industry=foo&q=bar
#to /list-of-bar-skills-in-foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /skills/keywords/list\.php\?industry=([^&]*)&q=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^skills/keywords/list\.php$ /list-of-%2-skills-in-%1? [L,R=301]
#rewrite new URL to the old one
RewriteRule ^list-of-([^-]+)-skills-in-([^-]+)/?$ /skills/keywords/list.php?industry=$1&q=$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I have a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error for some reasons.

Comment: @Seb The error is due to the `%{QUERY_STRING}` . You need to use `%{THE_REQUEST}` when redirecting and rewriting the same URI. Wait I fix it.

Comment: Thanks I've copied your code with %{THE_REQUEST} and now I have a 404 content not found error.

Comment: Ok it seems to work sorry some cache issues. I got the content of the page, but it seems that the variables from the URLs don't get passed. I need to look into it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: So how can I get the variables e.g. $query = $_GET['q']; now with this format: /list-of-analyst-skills-in-retail or is it not possible?